# Only first image uploaded, Upload multiple images individually in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Laravel Newbie here, would like to ask how to upload multiple images one by one. Multiple images work in one selection but putting images one by one to upload doesn't work and the first image only appears after submitting. Please help.

CONTROLLER

```php
    if (\Input::file('photos')) {
                $base_path =
                    dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../../../uploads/img/gallery/" . $add->id . "/";
                ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);
                //get last uploaded file name
                $files = (\Input::file('photos'));
                $list_image = $temp = explode(",", $request->list_image);
                foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
                        if (!is_null($value)) {
                        $temp = explode(".", $value->getClientOriginalName());
                        $newfilename = $value->getClientOriginalName();
                        if (!file_exists($base_path)) {
                            mkdir($base_path);
                            chmod($base_path, 0777);
                        }
                        $key = array_search($newfilename, $list_image);
                        if ($key == 0) {
                            $newfilename = $add->id . '_primary' . '.' . end($temp);
                        } else {
                                $newfilename = chr(64 + $key) . '_' . $newfilename;
                        }
                        $image = \Image::make($value);
                        // perform orientation using intervention
                        $image->orientate();
                        $new_width = $image->width();
                        $new_height = $image->height();
                        if ($new_width > 800) {
                            $percent = 0.7;
                            $new_width = $new_width * $percent;
                            $new_height = $new_height * $percent;
                        }

                        // resize image to fixed size
                        $image->resize($new_width, $new_height);

                        // create a new Image instance for inserting
                        $watermark = \Image::make(
                            public_path() . '/assets/img/icons/watermark.png',

                        );
                        // insert watermark at bottom-right corner with 10px offset
                        $image->insert(
                            public_path() . '/assets/img/icons/watermark.png',
                            'bottom-right',
                            10,
                            10,
                        );
                        $image->save($base_path . $newfilename);
                    }
                }

        }
```

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Using Laravel 5.1

Comment: You don't have to write this much of code just to upload multiple files, if you update your laravel version it would become much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
    $list_image = $temp = explode(",", $request->list_image);

if($request->hasfile('photos'))
        {
         $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/img/gallery/'. $add->id.'/'); 
            foreach($request->file('photos') as $k => $file)
            {

            $temp = explode(".", $file->getClientOriginalName());
            $newfilename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $key = array_search($newfilename, $list_image);
            if ($key == 0) {
                  $newfilename = $add->id . '_primary' . '.' . end($temp);
            } else {
                  $newfilename = chr(64 + $key) . '_' . $newfilename;
            }

                $name = $newfilename.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();           

                File::makeDirectory($destinationPath, $mode = 0777, true, true);
            $file->move($destinationPath, $name);
            $tdestinationPath = public_path('uploads/img/gallery/thumb'. $add->id.'/');
            try {
                    $img = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
                    $img->resize(50, 50, function ($constraint) {
                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    })->save($tdestinationPath.'/'.$name);      

                    $img->destroy(); 

                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $response_data=array('images'=>"",'success'=>0,'message'=>$e->getMessage());
            }

                $image_arr[] = $name;
            }
            $uploaded_img = implode(',',$image_arr);    
            if(!empty($hidden_property_img)){
                $uploaded_img = $hidden_property_img.','.$uploaded_img;
            }   
            $data['images'] = $uploaded_img;    

        }
```